# Does conditional independence lead to equality of expectations?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, conditional-expectation

In my probability class I was tackled with this question of the type to prove or disprove the following:

> Given random variables with PDF $ X,Y,Z $ and we know that given Y the variables X and Z are independent. We are asked to prove or disprove the following:
>
> $ \forall y,z \in R  $   :  $ E[X | Y=y , Z=z] = E[X | Y=y ] $

I have no real idea how to do this as I do not even know if it is true or false so I need the help on this and thanks to all.

Comment: By "continuous", is it meant that the variables have PDFs?

Comment: @Vossler yes it does that was the meaning

Comment: @Vossler : Please forgive that ambiguity I have added the clarification to the question, it was probably a language difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the statement is true. Let me abuse notation slightly and denote $p(x, y, z):=p_{X,Y,Z}(x, y, z)$ and analogously for other marginal distributions.

To prove this, we can see that even the PDFs coincide:

$$
p(x|y, z)=\frac{p(x, y, z)}{p(y, z)}=\frac{p(x,z|y)p(y)}{p(y,z)}=/\text{Conditional independence}/=\frac{p(x|y)\underbrace{p(z|y)p(y)}_{p(y,z)}}{p(y,z)}=p(x|y).
$$
Now, taking expectations of the left- and right-hand-side, we get the claim.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, X and Z are independent if the probability distribution of X is equal to the probability distribution of X given Z=z for any z. This would mean that $E[X]=E[X|Z=z]$.

Since here X and Z are independent given Y, we have $E[X]$ given (Y=y) equals $E[X|Z=z]$ given (Y=y) or in other words $E[X|Y=y]=E[X|Z=z,Y=y]$

Comment: To me this seems more like intuition than proof: for example, $E[X|Y=y]$ is, strictly speaking, not a random variable and thus is not covered by definition of conditional independence.

Comment: @Vossler, browngreen did not mention in any way that the expected values are independent, so I don't quite get your objection. browngreen's argument was simply that the pdf of $X|Y=y$ is the same as the one of $X|Y=y,Z=z$, therefore also their expectations have to match. Why isn't this a "proof"?

Comment: @bartgol Of course the assertion that the conditional distributions of $X$ conditionally on $[Y=y]$ and on $[Y=y,Z=z]$ coincide for every $(y,z)$ implies the desired result, but where is a proof of this assertion in the present answer?

Comment: Isn't that part of the question? "we know that given Y the variables X and Z are independent", means that $p(X=x|Y=y)=p(X=x|Y=y \mbox{ and } Z=z)$.

Comment: @bartgol Nope. What this means is that $P(X=x,Z=z\mid Y=y)=P(X=x\mid Y=y)P(Z=z\mid Y=y)$ for every $(x,y,z)$. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Comment: @Did Sure, you can use that definition of independence. Or you can say t hatA and B independent means that $p(A)=p(A|B)$. Which is precisely what you wrote, just flipped, with $A=X|Y$ and $B=Z|Y$. So why was I wrong?

Comment: @bartgol Once again, the question is trivial if one knows that conditional independence implies $P(X=x\mid Y=y)=P(X=x\mid Y=y,Z=z)$, but this is not the definition. Note additionally that the notations $A=X\mid Y$ and $B=Z\mid Y$ in your comment are problematic and probably refer to nonexistent entities. Is $A=X\mid Y$ supposed to denote an event? I fail to see which one that would be.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37523/discussion-between-bartgol-and-did).

Comment: Sorry, I do not chat.

Comment: I just discovered the two comments you added in chat. Many imprecise and/or dubious statements in them, but one part is frankly wrong: "the event $\{X=x|Y=y\}$" No, this is not an event, in fact "this" is nothing. Once again, if $A$ and $B$ are events, then $A$, $B$, $A\cap B$, $P(A)$, $P(B)$, $P(A\cap B)$, $P(A\mid B)$ are all well defined objects (the last one if $P(B)\ne0$) but $A\mid B$ is not. (But you seem to have backtracked from the even more awful $A=X\mid Y$ with $X$ and $Y$ random variables... and, if you have, this is a good thing.)

Comment: Forgot to ping previous comment. @bartgol